# What does $^ variable mean in Makefile?

Tags: linux, makefile, build, gnu-make

Unfortunately I can't find any reference in google, where some special Makefile variables listed with description.

What `$^` variable definitely means?

Sorry if obvious.

Comment: Did you try looking in the POSIX definition of make? https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xcu/make.html  Or, in the GNU make manual? https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/index.html which has an index: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Name-Index.html

Answer (score 0):

Each rule of a Makefile has a target and some prerequisites, the variable `$^` lists all the prerequisites with a space between the names.
You can see more details here https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Variables.html#Automatic-Variables